# How to extract valid IP Addr corresponding to a port using TCL regex

Tags: regex, tcl

set result "1 1.1.1.1\n2 2.2.2.2\n3 3.3.3.3\n4 4.4.4.4\n5 399.399.1.1"
puts "Result o/p\n$result"

Output:

```
Result o/p
1 1.1.1.1
2 2.2.2.2
3 3.3.3.3
4 4.4.4.4
```

Question - How to extract valid IP Addr corresponding to a port using TCL regex i.e.

```
User Input - 2 , Expected Output  - 2.2.2.2 (Valid IP)
User Input - 3 , Expected Output  - 399.399.1.1 (InValid IP)
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to process ip addresses. Use the [ip package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.html "IPv4 and IPv6 address manipulation")
 in Tcllib instead.

Comment: I get that. However the condition is to use regex , take user input = Port number, return corresponding IP Address with validation

Answer (score 0):

First, since the input is a valid list, I would "convert" it into an array:

```
% set result "1 1.1.1.1\n2 2.2.2.2\n3 3.3.3.3\n4 4.4.4.4\n5 399.399.1.1"
% array set results $result
% parray results
results(1) = 1.1.1.1
results(2) = 2.2.2.2
results(3) = 3.3.3.3
results(4) = 4.4.4.4
results(5) = 399.399.1.1
% set user_input 5
% puts $results($user_input)
399.399.1.1
```

Then, using Peter's suggestion:

```
% set fmt {User Input - %d, Expected Output - %s (%s IP)}
% set user_input 5
% puts [format $fmt $user_input $results($user_input) [expr {[::ip::version $results($user_input)] > 0 ? "Valid" : "Invalid"}]]
User Input - 5, Expected Output - 399.399.1.1 (Invalid IP)
% set user_input 4
% puts [format $fmt $user_input $results($user_input) [expr {[::ip::version $results($user_input)] > 0 ? "Valid" : "Invalid"}]]
User Input - 4, Expected Output - 4.4.4.4 (Valid IP)
```

Using a regular expression:

```
% set re_octet {\m(?:\d\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\M}
% set re_ip "$re_octet\\.$re_octet\\.$re_octet\\.$re_octet"
% set user_input 5
% puts [format $fmt $user_input $results($user_input) [expr {[regexp $re_ip $results($user_input)] ? "Valid" : "Invalid"}]]
User Input - 5, Expected Output - 399.399.1.1 (Invalid IP)
% set user_input 4
% puts [format $fmt $user_input $results($user_input) [expr {[regexp $re_ip $results($user_input)] ? "Valid" : "Invalid"}]]
User Input - 4, Expected Output - 4.4.4.4 (Valid IP)
```